# How to format stored data in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a data like below and i want to show is data according to the format in my template.
my data,

```
[ 

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587daf9604a192098ac39fe1"),
    "uuid" : "3a06d55e-b2b0-4e24-9c17-fdf96a3827e6",
    "active" : true,
    "created" : ISODate("2017-01-17T05:45:58.919Z"),
    "description" : "khsjq<br />wsjqwsqw<br />wwsnqwksqwsws"
}, 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587db2f404a192098ac39fe3"),
    "uuid" : "454a1ff2-d64d-48d6-bb01-b3bc814aca01",
    "active" : true,
    "created" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:00:20.439Z"),
    "description" : "iifdjasda<br />dlsldsad<br />asd<br />sadsadasdasdsadsadsad"
}]
```

my js

```
   $.each(vm.courseObj.course_module, function (i, v) {
          v.description = $sce.trustAsHtml(v.description);
          vm.courseModulearr.push(v);
      });
```

Unfortunatly it not reflecting in my view ,it is shown as 
iifdjasda
dlsldsad
asd
sadsadasdasdsadsadsad in my view.Can anyone help me.Thanks.

Comment: Yeh so that is what the br is supposed to do..

Comment: it should display in next line.

Comment: i hgot but putting ng-bind-html in my view but when i try to update it is not geeting

Comment: I have posted my plunkr...Look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at my plunkr..

https://plnkr.co/edit/EVPDSFAUyr55jDDlVOVV?p=preview

```
  app.filter("unsafe",function($sce){

        return function(val){
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
        }
      })
```

You should use a filter and ng-bind-html to parse the html content

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: i forgot to keep data-bind-html

Comment: can you help in another question.

Comment: its abt jqx-grid pagination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691515/how-to-add-pagination-to-jqgrid-in-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment70580824_41691515

Answer (score 1):

create a `trust` filter like this

```
.filter('trust', [
    '$sce',
    function($sce) {
      return function(value, type) {
        return $sce.trustAs(type || 'html', value);
      }
    }
  ]);
```

and bind value like this

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlData | trust"></div>
```

checkout my working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/0tLso4vg/)