# How to add pagination to jqgrid in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination, jqgrid

I implemented jqgrid for my data but recently i am trying to keep pagination for it unfortunately,i am unable to find the best source for it.If required i can paste my js code and here is my template,

```
div class="work-item-table grid" id="workitems">
        <jqx-grid id="events-grid" jqx-on-filter="filter" jqx-settings="settings" jqx-create="vm.createWidget"></jqx-grid>
    </div>
```

Can anyone please provide me help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use **jqgrid**, **jsxgrid** (http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-getting-started.htm) or some other product? You use `jqx-` prefix in all names and attributes.

Comment: It is a jquery library...not available in angular..So either u can wrap it in a directive or simply use jquery for this